# Salesforce Ant Migration Tool - HomePageComponent

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, migration-tool

I'm trying to figure out when using the Salesforce Metadata API (salesforce ant migration tool) how to pull back the custom links defined within the HomePageComponents. I've pulled down a blanket from this metadata type with no luck using the wildcard. In a lot of the metadata retrieval calls as in the case for Sobjects, you need to define standard objects such as Account, Opportunity, Lead, etc. I'm unsure if I have to do the same thing for HomePageComponents. I've also tried using the describe listMetadata with no luck on finding out how to pull back this info. Any help is appreciated.

[image: HomePageComponent Image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to retrieve CustomPageWebLink with following package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomPageWebLink</name>
    </types>
    <version>36.0</version>
</Package>
```

And this is what i got.

[image]

PS: I have used workbench.developerforce.com --> Migration --> retrieve API for this to prove it works.

Comment: I did the same thing, sadly when i go to retrieve meta data as your example describes for CustomPageWebLink ("metadataDescribeAndList.php?type=WebLink"), these are weblinks to objects, and not the homepagecomponents' weblinks

Answer (score -1):

According to this link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm, wildcard is allowed for HomePageComponent metadata type

Comment: Could you maybe post a sample of how to achieve this, instead of just a link to an article?

Comment: Currently this does not give you the data from the configuration.